# Update a different component (nested on same level) after http call to Firebase has successfully posted data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, components, parent-child

I am trying to post some data to the firebase DB and prompt a success message which redirects the user to the same page, resetting the form in case the post request has been successful.

The component involved are `add-review.component.ts` and `addReview.service.ts`.

`add-review.component.ts` is in the `add-review` folder and `addReview.service.ts` in the `service` folder, these two folders are on the same level, nested under `app`.

After the service has successfully posted the data, I have been trying to let the other component know, so that the form could be reset() and re-initiated, without luck.

I can't do an `eventEmitter` and an `@Output()` because the `add-review.component.ts` is served through a `<router-outlet>`, so there's no direct parent-child link.

Some code now:

add-review.component.ts:

```
onSubmitReview() {
    const newReview = this.addReviewForm.value;
    this.addReviewService.addNewReview(newReview);
  }
```

add-review.service.ts:

```
addNewReview(newReview: Review) { 
    this.http.post('https://myApp-6c621.firebaseio.com/reviews.json', newReview).subscribe(reportData => {
      console.log(reportData);
}
```

I would like to:

1. if the data has been successfully posted, return to the page and reset the form (in the service file I am already redirecting using `this.router.navigate(['/add-review']);`) and it works fine.
2. else, return to the same page and the data is still in the form inputs.

How can I update the `add-review.component.ts` from the `add-review.service.ts` upon successful post request?

I know there might be an easier way, i.e. perform the post request right on the component, but I am interested in how to communicate this sort of things between same-level router-outlet-nested components.

Comment: Why subscribe inside the service? Normally your component would do the subscribe. Once you do that you can do whatever you need within the subscribe callback.

Comment: I was subscribing just to log the reportData call in the console, thanks for pointing it out. Also, I wanted to fire an alert with a different message in case of successful or unsuccessful outcome of the post (so if reportData is true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the Observable in the component `add-review.component.ts:`

```
onSubmitReview() {
    const newReview = this.addReviewForm.value;
    this.addReviewService.addNewReview(newReview).subscribe(
        response => {
            //reset here using reset() method of forms
        }, error => {
            console.log(error) //catch error
        });
}
```

In your service:

```
addNewReview(newReview: Review) { 
    return this.http.post('https://myApp-6c621.firebaseio.com/reviews.json', newReview);
}
```

Note: Use the reset() method. Refer this doc: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've used your code as it is, and when subscribing to `this.addReviewService.addNewReview` I receive the error message *Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.*" in the code, and "*Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined*" in the console. I've tried creating an Observable then, like this `  response$: Observable<AddReviewService>;` and subscribing to it. The code error disappeared but I still get the "*Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined*" in the console. Thanks.

Comment: My bad. I was forgetting the `return` before the http call. It works perfectly, thank you very much!! :D